# how to add return types to range function?

Tags: typescript

this code is from [you don't know JS yet](https://github.com/liweinandever/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/get-started/apB.md#suggested-solutions), and I'm trying to add types to it, but I'm confused.

```js
function range(start: number, end?: number) {
  start = Number(start) || 0;

  if (end === undefined) {
    return function getEnd(end: number) {
      return getRange(start, end);
    };
  } else {
    end = Number(end) || 0;
    return getRange(start, end);
  }

  // **********************

  function getRange(start: number, end: number) {
    var ret: number[] = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      ret.push(i);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}

range(3, 3); // [3]
range(3, 8); // [3,4,5,6,7,8]
range(3, 0); // []

var start3 = range(3);
var start4 = range(4);

start3(3); // [3]
start3(8); // [3,4,5,6,7,8]
start3(0); // []

start4(6); // [4,5,6]
```

The error info is:

This expression is not callable.
Not all constituents of type '((end: number) => number[]) | number[]' are callable.
Type 'number[]' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

I'm trying to find the answer, but still don't understand. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has looked at your `return` statements and *inferred* that the return type of `range` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `((end: number) => number[]) | number[]`.  So when you call `range()`, the compiler knows only that it returns either another function *or* an array of numbers.  It doesn't understand that there is any relationship between *how* you call `range()` and *which* of those two types the return value will actually be:

```
const r33 = range(3, 3); // [3]
// const r33: ((end: number) => number[]) | number[]

var start3 = range(3);
// var start3: ((end: number) => number[]) | number[]
```

See? both `r33` and `start3` are seen as the same type, something which *might* be an array, but *might* be a function instead.  It can't see the difference between `start3(3)` and `r33(3)`.

So if you call `start3(3)`, the compiler will warn you that it can't be sure that you're not calling an array as if it were a function.  Unless you explicitly *check* `start3` before calling it:

```
var start3 = range(3);
if (typeof start3 !== "function") throw new Error();

start3(3); // okay
start3(8); // okay
start3(0); // okay
```

Or unless you just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it is a function:

```
(start4 as Extract<typeof start4, Function>)(6); // okay
```

Neither of which are what you want to do.

---

So the compiler can't really infer the relationship between the number of inputs and the output types.  But there are ways to *tell* the compiler this information, so that callers can have an easier time.

Perhaps the most straightforward way is to make `range()` an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).  You start by providing a set of *call signature declarations*, corresponding to the different distinct input-output relationships callers can expect:

```
// call signatures
function range(start: number, end: number): number[];
function range(start: number): (end: number) => number[];
```

Then you write the implementation as before:

```
function range(start: number, end?: number) {
  // same impl here
}
```

This compiles fine, although the compiler does not check it very thoroughly.  If, for example, I mixed up the two return types in those call signatures (put `number[]` on the second one and `(end: number) => number[]` on the first one), the compiler would not catch such a mistake.  Overload function implementations are checked more loosely than normal function implementations, so you need to be careful.

Anyway, now callers can call `range` and have more reasonable behavior:

```
const r33 = range(3, 3); // [3]
// const r33: number[]

var start3 = range(3);
// var start3: (end: number) => number[]
```

Now the compiler knows that `r33` is an array and `start3` is a function.  The calls after this will work as expected.

---

The other way to do this is to make `range()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function whose return type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on how the function is called:

```
function range<T extends [end: number] | []>(start: number, ...[end]: T):
  T extends [] ? (end: number) => number[] : number[] {
  start = Number(start) || 0;

  if (end === undefined) {
    return function getEnd(end: number) {
      return getRange(start, end);
    } as any;
  } else {
    end = Number(end) || 0;
    return getRange(start, end) as any;
  }

  // same getRange impl here
}
```

Here we are saying that, after the `start` argument, you can expect that the [rest of the arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) `T` will be assignable either to a single-element [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) corresponding to the `end` parameter, or an empty tuple corresponding to no `end` parameter.  Then the return value of `T extends [] ? (end: number) => number[] : number[]` evaluates either to a function type or to an array type depending on `T`.

The compiler still cannot follow the logic inside the function to verify that the actual returns comply with this generic-conditional-type (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for more information) but unlike overloads the compiler will complain about this.  So for now that means you need something like type assertions to make the return statements compile without warning (see the `as any` I added), and thus this solution turns out to be quite as unsafe as overloads.

---

Either way, you need to be careful that the input/output relationship you have expressed by the call signature(s) is actually properly implemented.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJJAMwFdh4AXDAe2CTRGCwgAopqQ1qAuJMHJgARhDQAaJBGAATAPwCho8QEo8REiS49qSALxIAcsLFpO3XuoA+1pAAYA3EU1aMpJOxmyD+w5VkIUgxgCFl1AmItEjQIanI0RgoqWgYkNmoAUTkvOSVTNQ0o6Ji4hMYMgCUWNgtdKW9VZ2KtAF9m6NbpABsoZEiS6TkDYwLzRqRbBw6S2PjE9Ljq1g4dXga5JtcSVpcWgHp9pAAqU7Pzi8vjvejkmnoKpZrVy35BMY3ZfJU0CO2tABuPCYcW+ZgA2gBdEZQma3OhoTzdOJIDAjNbURyopAAHkM3ixGAA1ES-i1onMAHQwchQAAW7AwW3JSF2LLm5RBmP+bJ2NyQ8AYXCYAGYRSNmCt2CKpCKmkhDkhwSLIa5FYLgMK0GKBOxcl93j91PoAHyGiGQmzm8RQ1yS2oypAADnliuVEgALBIAKwSABsEgA7BInaqovaOI77K6jrbCK4gYiMeLDBHpcySIrE0hk7r9WDCqbrWgoVblBbXO5PNQAJ4wCB0DzJpAAQj8SAARHdUsAO+pqHS0HQAO6CCCjzJoIfmZkJ4EYj0S57sD2zqLJ9NYxV0ADWIBrrg3Lq3R13+8PrxF7GjJ6QZ4P8aidV4i5AUCQmQAHtRmDQcbX60bHNXi9JAADFKHuBgTVUdg-RjO89wfNkiFASBYAQZAUABbofEiVxuweJhlwxAtJCGA1yzUMjYQIyCe2IqVSOLVRdW8MjjTNKiS0hGZCLSNNmO4z5FBYopogxEYTB+Z9qBsOwnH5Egq31Xx-DkIIQjCMlBg5BZ+MeLIcnYsSBkGLlOSqEjXk+DMSnaHkej6cSSm8KSxn1eTpn+Up5kM5ZagxWy4VZJSFSOK5IquMKDMWagApeXQyM+DiXOibM5ho6FDFollSARJEUTRQwMUJXF8TkQkSR08yqRpelGTszofIshY5hC3lQsfEgNS1MUlylR05VvZUw0zI5er0bURSy-k00dY9wqVGUvV9ANg1DO1lyjBC4znJNLwGh07KzedLzYvIxKLbi9qibMFyOjhV2aC9dCvYaltG17eCvRa3RWn1-SDEMxuAt7r12sNvuoD04N21b-TDFDCDQ6A4EQJAAGEGFkDAexAboXNiiMcQAFWkb9vHfcETO46E7ChE1ZOSpBKTZmm5EhARSdY-5yYgSm5Gp6F5E8Wmxk44soSQLK0rB3h3JkjEvMU7q3A8VS-HUwJglCcI5d8zlYoybJZHzUyWsNhYrKYmyKKatokDfJ3gBrDqnP6Fq3MMaSzE8yYFJCq3-Os+p7ad98WDdnkwsVKL47OGL6KIm3AteFnxaNA2kAy0EpeypVeJa-LEXYZE9GK+XMWxPEKKq0ls986laQZJkg663SyjauIOtcZGeqFKb+tTbbZV2lU1QmwfRRm-O5tH51x89QH1pBrbBqkG9Pqhu6zrex7N0nnO95+i7KIlgwuLGW6SHukCD+e-kNw+-7QaPJeEdXzb10vCGRp37QIE4YjU-kjIAA)

Comment: Thank you very much, jaclz